# listen server in applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a messaging application and I want that the application listens the server on background and when new message comes, fires notification. 
I tried to do that with timers and backgroundtasks, i can listen the server and the application fires the notification but when i reopen the application, i can not interact with anything, like the application is locked. Can you suggest any proper way to do that?

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(sbCheckServerRecords) name:@"UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification" object:nil];
    }
    -(void) sbCheckServerRecords{
          self.tmrCheckRecords = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1] interval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(sbCheckRecords) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
          [self.tmrCheckRecords fire];
     }
    -(void) sbCheckRecords{
        @try{
        if(any message comes)
           notify user;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Please post some of what you have tried.  This will make it much easier to help you move forward.

Answer (score 0):

I have used timer as dispatch_source_t and
this class worked for me:

https://gist.github.com/maicki/7622108